# Ansible: filter an item from a list of object in a json file

Tags: json, ansible, set, json-query, fact

I have in ansible the following code:

```
---
  - name: "Retrieve ID for group {{onboarding.repo.subGroup}}"
    uri:
      method: GET
      return_content: yes
      validate_certs: "{{gitlab_validate_certs}}"
      url: "{{ gitlab_api_url }}/api/v4/groups?search={{onboarding.repo.subGroup}}"
      headers:
        Private-Token: "{{ gitlab_api_token }}"
    register: uri_response

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ uri_response['content'] }}"

  - set_fact:
      groupID: "{{ uri_response['content'] | from_json | json_query([*].[?name=='{{onboarding.repo.subGroup}}'].id) }}"
```

The get method retrieve a json list like the following one:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"name1"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"name2"
  },
  ...
]
```

With the set_fact module I am trying to get the id on an item that correspond to a specific name. I have tried many json_query syntax (for instance `.[?name=='{{onboarding.repo.subGroup}}'].id` or `[?name=='{{onboarding.repo.subGroup}}'].id)`, without success. I saw many different examples online, but they were different because the list was the value of a key, like the following:

```
key:
    [
      {...},
      {...},
      ...
    ]
```

And I saw different examples working with a query syntax like `key.[?name=='{{onboarding.repo.subGroup}}'].id`

I cannot find a way to adapt that query to my case. Can anyone help me on finding the right syntax?

Regards,
Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Get the id on an item that corresponds to a specific name."***

A: Convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  content: "{{ uri_response.content|
               items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='id') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  content:
    name1: 1
    name2: 2
```

Use the dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ content[item]|default('undef') }}"
      loop:
        - name1
        - name2
        - name3
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: '1'
  msg: '2'
  msg: undef
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    uri_response:
      content:
        [
          {
            "id":1,
            "name":"name1"
          },
          {
            "id":2,
            "name":"name2"
          }
        ]
    content: "{{ uri_response.content|items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='id') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ content[item]|default('undef') }}"
      loop:
        - name1
        - name2
        - name3
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the json list. I had mistakenly wrote '=' instead of ':', so I guess the 'regex_replace' is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with the following code:
  - vars:
      content: "{{ uri_response.content }}"
      content_dict: "{{ content | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='id') }}"
    set_fact:
      groupID: "{{ content_dict[onboarding.repo.subGroup] | default('undef')}}"
I had to define both "content" and "content_dict", otherwise if I give uri_response.content as input to items2dict, I receive the follwing error:
  "items2dict requires a list, got <class 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText'> instead"
Hoping with this comment to have enough reputation to give upvotes

Comment: Never put larger chunks of code into a comment. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). There is no *content_dict* after you clarified the structure and after I updated the answer.